# Search by custom attribute in Intercom ruby gem

Tags: ruby, intercom

I am using Intercom ruby gem. One of my `company` responses looks like below:

```
 @company_id="648",
 @created_at=1578937499,
 @custom_attributes=
  {"cname"=>nil,
   "contacts"=>1,
   "ein"=>"xyz123"
  }
```

In order to search by company_id, I can do this: `intercom.companies.find(company_id: 648)` (Reference: https://github.com/intercom/intercom-ruby#search-for-customers) . However, I want to search by one of the custom attributes `ein`. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible at the moment

From the latest API (version 2.3 right now) there is only ability to search contacts (users/leads) https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#search-for-contacts

Looks like retrieving companies can only be done via

- `name` / `company_id`: https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#view-a-company
- `tag_id` / `segment_id`: https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#list-companies